# XML Schema uniqueness over key elements

Tags: xml, xsd

Say I have the following piece of xml schema code :

```
 <xs:key name="item1">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//tns:itemone" />
      <xs:field xpath="@id" />
 </xs:key>

 <xs:key name="item2">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//tns:itemtwo" />
      <xs:field xpath="@id" />
 </xs:key>
```

Each of the items (itemone, itemtwo) has an `id` which is unique but only in their "scope". All I want is to make this uniqueness globally.

For example, I want that this should not be valid when the schema is applied :

```
<items>
        <itemone id="sameitem">
                ...
        </itemone>
        <itemtwo id="sameitem">
                ...
        </itemtwo>
</items>
```

This is not valid because the `id` is the same. Waiting for ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the selector using a wildcard will make sure the key is unique across all descendants.

```
 <xs:key name="item1">
     <xs:selector xpath=".//*" />
     <xs:field xpath="@id" />
 </xs:key>
```

(Single `/` instead of `//` would select direct children only)

However, using the type `xs:ID` may be more appropriate for this use case, if the intent is uniqueness for all attributes with that type across the entire document.

```
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
```